# Serialize DOM to FileOutputStream using Xerces

Tags: java, xml, dom, xerces

I am using [this](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152) link to generate XML file using DOM. It says that "Xerces parser is bundled with the JDK 1.5 distribution.So you need not download the parser separately."

However, when I write the following line in my Eclipse Helios it gives compile-time error even though I have Java 1.6 in my system.

```
import org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer;
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Xerces is indeed bundled with the JDK but you should use it with the JAXP API under `javax.xml.parsers`. Check the output of the program below.

Also, to serialize an XML `Document`, you should use DOM Level 3 Load and Save (present in the JDK) or an XSLT transformation with no stylesheet (identity transformation). The rest is dependent on a specific implementation. The Xerces XMLSerializer is deprecated:

> Deprecated. This class was deprecated in Xerces 2.9.0. It is recommended that new applications use the DOM Level 3 LSSerializer or JAXP's Transformation API for XML (TrAX) for serializing XML. See the Xerces documentation for more information.

Here is an example of serialization with DOM level 3:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.*;

public class DOMExample3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();    
        DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("XML 3.0 LS 3.0");
        if (impl == null) {
            System.out.println("No DOMImplementation found !");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.printf("DOMImplementationLS: %s\n", impl.getClass().getName());

        LSParser parser = impl.createLSParser(
                DOMImplementationLS.MODE_SYNCHRONOUS,
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml");
        // http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
        System.out.printf("LSParser: %s\n", parser.getClass().getName());

        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Document doc = parser.parseURI(args[0]);

        LSSerializer serializer = impl.createLSSerializer();
        LSOutput output = impl.createLSOutput();
        output.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        output.setByteStream(System.out);
        serializer.write(doc, output);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here is an example with an identity transformation:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class DOMExample2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        System.out.println("Parsing XML document...");
        Document doc;
        doc = parser.parse(args[0]);

        // Xerces Java 2

        /* Deprecated. This class was deprecated in Xerces 2.9.0.
         * It is recommended that new applications use the DOM Level 3
         * LSSerializer or JAXP's Transformation API for XML (TrAX)
         * for serializing XML and HTML.
         * See the Xerces documentation for more information.
         */  
        /*
        System.out.println("XERCES: Displaying XML document...");
        OutputFormat of = new OutputFormat(doc, "ISO-8859-1", true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        BaseMarkupSerializer bms = new XMLSerializer(pw, of);
        bms.serialize(doc);
*/
        // JAXP

        System.out.println("JAXP: Displaying XML document...");
        TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        System.out.println(transFactory.getClass().getName());
        //transFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 2);
        Transformer idTransform = transFactory.newTransformer();
        idTransform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        idTransform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"yes");
        // Apache default indentation is 0
        idTransform.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");                
        Source input = new DOMSource(doc);
        Result output = new StreamResult(System.out);
        idTransform.transform(input, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you think it might be considered as an answer, could you flag it ?

Comment: I increased the count by clicking "This answer is useful" :)

Comment: Made some Eclipse detail formatters based on this: https://gist.github.com/xkr47/9595446

Answer (score 1):

It will be in, IIRC, `com.sun.org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer`. However, those are private classes and likely to change at any time. I suggest using the standard public APIs (`javax.*` and friends) instead. (Use the transform API without any XSLT.)