# Serialize a DOM document in UTF-8

Tags: java, dom, utf-8, utf-16

I have been trying to get rid of all  com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal packages in my code replacing them with stable alternatives.

This is one method I've replaced...

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.LineSeparator;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer;
...
...

    /**
     * @param source
     * @param target
     * @throws IOException
     */
    protected static void serialize( Document source, Writer target ) throws IOException
    {
        OutputFormat outputFormat = new OutputFormat( (Document) source );
        outputFormat.setLineSeparator( LineSeparator.Windows );
        // format.setIndenting(true);

        outputFormat.setLineWidth( 0 );
        outputFormat.setPreserveSpace( true );

        XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer( target, outputFormat );
        serializer.asDOMSerializer();
        serializer.serialize( source );
    } // end serialize
```

this is an alternative I found...

```
/**
 * @param source
 * @param target
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws IllegalAccessException 
 * @throws InstantiationException 
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 * @throws ClassCastException 
 */
protected static void serialize( Document source, Writer target ) throws Exception
{
    DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
    DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation( "LS" );
    LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();
    target.write( writer.writeToString(source) );
} // end serialize
```

However, its showing a difference in the xml that is being produced.

It creates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

How can this be modified to create UTF-8 instead?

Comment: There are many code snippets in the net with reading and writing XML. `org.w3c.Document.getXmlEncoding()` would give "UTF-16" after reading. But there is no setter as the writing uses an encoding which should be patched in the `encoding` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `LSOutput`:

```
LSOutput domOutput = impl.createLSOutput();
domOutput.setEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
domOutput.setCharacterStream(stringWriter);
```

See the response here for more details:

[Change the com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer & com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315480/change-the-com-sun-org-apache-xml-internal-serialize-xmlserializer-com-sun-org)