# updating the deprecated XMLSerializer

Tags: java, deprecated, xmlserializer

I have the following (old) code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XMLSerializer output = new XMLSerializer(baos, new OutputFormat(document));
output.serialize(document);
bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

I want to update the code above  so that it no longer includes deprecated code. I had a look at [LSOuput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSOutput.html) as a replacement but I'm not really sure how to go about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer & com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315480/change-the-com-sun-org-apache-xml-internal-serialize-xmlserializer-com-sun-org)

Comment: I couldn't really relate to the answer given to that question.