# Error on XMLSerializer

Tags: java, json, xml

I'm getting on line y setTypeHintsCompatibility( false ) is undefined for the type xmlserializer.
What am i doing wrong exactly...
Any help ?

```
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.*; 
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import net.sf.json.JSON;
    import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat;
    import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer;

    public class JsonForm extends HttpServlet {

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

            String str = "{'FirstName':'Mike'}";  
            JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON( str ); 
            XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();  
            xmlSerializer.setTypeHintsCompatibility( false );  //Line y
            String xml = xmlSerializer.write( json );  
            System.out.println(xml); 


        }

    }
```

Comment: Compilation error or runtime error? Please add the exact stacktrace or error description. You probably have an older version of the jar containing XMLSerializer.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna compilation error

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna can you advise me with the appropriate .jar please

Answer (score -1):

Looking at this question: [Change the com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer & com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315480/change-the-com-sun-org-apache-xml-internal-serialize-xmlserializer-com-sun-org) I think you may be using Xerces.
If I understand correctly, such classes are included in your JVM and are not meant to be publicly used as you are trying to do. Change your code as explained here: [Serialize DOM to FileOutputStream using Xerces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257748/serialize-dom-to-fileoutputstream-using-xerces) .

If you are trying to convert JSON to XML, why don't you try this simpler approach? [Converting JSON to XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977979/converting-json-to-xml-in-java)